# Parcel and aliases

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parceljs

In my `tsconfig.json` I've defined aliases:

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": [ "ClientApp/*" ]
},
```

Parcel doesn't seem to understand this, since Parcel tries to download components from npm:

```
  C:\src\xx\ClientApp\components\deployment\home\home.vue.html:1:1: Unknown word
 1 | <script src="./home.ts"></script>
    | ^
 npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
 npm ERR! Could not install from "@\dto" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

The declaration in the typescript file:

```
import {
    GetVersionHistory, GetVersionHistoryResult, GetVersionHistorySeries,
    GetApplicationVersions, GetApplicationVersionsResult, GetApplicationVersionsResultItem
} from "@/dto/Modules/Versions";
```

How can I correct that?

Comment: check this out : https://parceljs.org/module_resolution.html#aliases